# Trying to view info from dropdown list on my table

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have two pages. one contains my drop-down list of branches, while the second is my php connection page
I want to select a branch from my drop down list, click process and then a table displays Branch-name, Status, Amount and Date2
Whenever a click process, I get an empty table with just the headers
here are my codes:

branch.php

```
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<form method = "POST" action = "getuser.php" >
<select name="branch">
  <option value="">Select a branch:</option>
  <option value="1">Maths</option>
  <option value="3">English</option>
  <option value="4">Biology</option>
  <option value="5">Chemistry</option>
  <option value="6">Economics</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type = "submit" name "submit" value ="Process">
</form>
<br>
```

getuser.php

```
<?php
//$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','modem');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
    if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $branch = $_POST['branch'];

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%M %Y' )as date2
        FROM bm_ibadan_division
        WHERE branch = '$branch'
        ORDER BY date ASC");

        echo "<table align='center'  width='400px' border='1'>
        <tr>
        <th>Branch</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Date2</th>
        </tr>";

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['branch'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['date2'] . "</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    } else echo "access denied";
        mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','','modem');
```

if(!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error($con));

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

```
    $branch = $_POST['branch'];

    $result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT( date, '%M %Y' )as date2 FROM bm_ibadan_division WHERE branch = $branch ORDER BY date ASC");

    echo "<table align='center'  width='400px' border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>Branch</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Date2</th>
    </tr>";

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['branch'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date2'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";
} 
else
{
    echo "access denied"; 
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: thanks SneakingOzone but after using your advice, all i get is access denied